# Оптимизация кода (цикл, условия)

Tags: python, pandas, циклы, условия

У меня есть google таблица, которая, к примеру, выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

далее через `DataFrame` библиотеки `Pandas` я получаю данные из этой таблицы для дальнейшего анализа. Есть некий `Архив` и есть связка `Номер - Цвет`. Задача - подсчитать количество каждого цвета в столбце `D`, но с условием, что номера из столбца `C` могут дублироваться столбце `A`, в таком случае количество `Красного` должно просуммироваться с `Разноцветным`. Дублироваться могут только номера, которым сопоставлен `Красный` цвет. (если это значение дублируется, то считать этот цвет не Красным, а Разноцветным и суммировать соответственно количество таких дублей не с Красными, а с Разноцветными).

Касаемо кода. Вот, что я смог придумать. Он вроде полностью отрабатывает задачу, но выглядит довольно грязно и слабочитаем. Можете подсказать как его причесать и возможно избавиться от многовложенности условий.

```
import pandas as pd
from sheets import *

# Столбец A (архив)
archive = pd.DataFrame(test_sheet.get_values('A2:A21'), columns=['Номер'])
# Столбцы C,D (номер, цвет)
column = pd.DataFrame(test_sheet.get_values('C2:D21'), columns=['Номер', 'Цвет'])

color = {
    'Красный': 'Красный|красный',
    'Белый': 'Белый|белый',
    'Синий': 'Синий|синий',
    'Зеленый': 'Зеленый|зеленый',
    'Разноцветный': 'Разноцветный|разноцветный',
    'Оранжевый': 'Оранжевый|оранжевый'
}

to_archive = 0  # Перенос в архив через данную переменную

for key in color.keys():
    col_ = column[column['Цвет'].str.contains(color[key])]
    if key == 'Красный' and len(col_) > 0:
        double = pd.merge(archive, col_, how='inner')
        if len(double) > 0:
            to_archive = len(double)
            print(f'{key}: {len(col_) - to_archive}')
        else:
            print(f'{key}: {len(col_) - len(double)}')
    elif key == 'Разноцветный':
        print(f'{key}: {len(col_) + to_archive}')
    else:
        print(f'{key}: {len(col_)}')
print('******************')
```

Вывод:

```
Красный: 3
Белый: 2
Синий: 3
Зеленый: 3
Разноцветный: 5
Оранжевый: 4
******************
```

Добавляю [ссылку](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JvY-Q5-WHjn_O1AhjUG2xuPqXGEm8AcDvTyncUim-JM/edit?usp=share_link) на файл с исходными данными

Comment: вы бы привели исходные данные, чтобы не гадать на кофейной гуще.

Comment: @strawdog, спасибо, что обратили внимание на мой вопрос, какие именно исходные данные требуются? Вроде бы в описании учтены все данные, если что-то ещё требуется - дополню

Comment: нужна часть вашего исходного датафрейма , чтобы было с чем работать.

Comment: вообще, опишите словами алгоритм, как у вас из данных на картинке получился результат как в вопросе. мне вот не понятно.

Comment: @strawdog, задача посчитать сколько раз встречается каждый цвет в столбце D (это прям слово, не заливка ячейки или текса этим цветом, т.е. это некий фильтр для значений из соседнего столбца), но в случае подсчета красного цвета нужно сверять значение напротив него из столбца С на предмет дублирования этого значения в столбце А. И если это значение дублируется, то считать этот цвет не `Красным`, а `Разноцветным` и суммировать соответственно количество таких дублей не с Красными, а с Разноцветными.

Comment: теперь понятно. осталось получить пример исходных данных. их можно выложить. например, в формате csv на файлообменник или на google docs

Comment: @strawdog, готово, ссылку на файл добавил

Comment: Ну тут явно `left join` какой-то напрашивается. Но в целом задача путанная.

Comment: @CrazyElf, буду признателен, если опубликуете свой вариант решения. Если требуются дополнительные данные или пояснения - дополню с радостью

Comment: @ZxNuClear Тут надо всё же подумать, понять задачу, а у меня работы полно, нет времени думать ((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы совсем не используете инструментарий pandas. Ваша задача решается в полторы строки:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

df.loc[df["Номер"].isin(df["Архив"]), "Цвет"] = "Разноцветный"
res = df.value_counts("Цвет")
```

получаете res:

```
Цвет
Разноцветный    5
Оранжевый       4
Зеленый         3
Красный         3
Синий           3
Белый           2
dtype: int64
```